# C# NpgsqlException mock Moq

Tags: c#, unit-testing, mocking, moq, npgsql

I want to mock some method to throw NpgsqlException, like this:

```
_someMock.Setup(x => x.SomeMethod(It.IsAny<int>())).Throws(new NpgsqlException());
```

But there is no public constructor for NpgsqlException, I tried to use reflection instead but it found no constructors for this exception(even private)

Comment: At here https://github.com/npgsql/npgsql/blob/master/src/Npgsql/NpgsqlException.cs/#L33 you can see that there is actually a parameter less constructor for `NpgsqlException`. Though it not seems very logical you might use a version of npgsql library in which this class has not a parameter less constructor.

Comment: Docs says it has a parameterless constructor http://www.npgsql.org/api/Npgsql.NpgsqlException.html You could also use one of the other overloads `public NpgsqlException(string message)`

Comment: Looks like this public constructor appears in a newer version than that what I'm using. Minie is 2.2.7.0

Comment: 2.2.7 is an ancient version by now, it's strongly suggested to upgrade to 3.2. Incidentally, that version also has the public constructors you need.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
//Arrange
var pgException = new PostgresException("messageText", "severity", "invariantSeverity", "sqlState");
        
//Setup
_someMock.Setup(x => x.SomeMethod(It.IsAny<int>())).ThrowsAsync(pgException);
```